# asp.net web api 2 attribute route is not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this route in an API controller called `Recruiting`:

```
 ResponseType(typeof (int))]
 [Route("Recruiting/setprimary/")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutUpdatePrimary(string userId, string orgId)
 {
     return Ok();
 }
```

I am trying to hit this routing via ajax like so:

```
 self.updatePrimary = function () {
    var orgKey = self.selectedOrgKey();
    alert(orgKey);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Recruiting/setprimary/" + "?userId=" + userId + "&?orgId=" + orgKey,
        data: null,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            bootbox.alert('Changes saved successfully.');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            bootbox.alert('An error occured while trying to set primary organisation. Please try again :/');
        }
    });
    return true;
};
```

Fiddler is saying it cannot find the route. What do I have wrong here?

Comment: When you watch the network traffic in your developer tools what is the full URI when you try to hit that action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your request url: Instead of `"&?orgId="`..it should be `"&orgId="`